# Search text file and put matching results in listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET project in which there is a form where there is a TextBox control, a ListBox control and an external text file that contains a list of outlook folder paths for client emails.

Essentially, the user enters into the text box the name of a client and/or their unique reference number, presses the search button (yes - I know I could make the results appear as they type, I want a button!) and it comes up with the matching results for the company name or serial number that are in the text file and puts them in the list box, with the full path of the outlook email folder.

For example:

If I put into the textbox: "06967759-274D-40B2-A3EB-D7F9E73727D7"

It would put the following result into the listbox:

"EIS Admin\Contacts{06967759-274D-40B2-A3EB-D7F9E73727D7}"

And the user can then go to that folder and find the email(s).

I have gone through several revisions both of my own code and code pasted from online with people having the same issue, only to have Visual Studio throw no errors, run the code and have no luck, with it doing nothing but clearing the list box, and not showing matching results of any kind.

**I understand this may be a repeat question but I am extremely confused**, can't get anything to work and need some help regarding my issue.

Here is the current code (from online - not mine):

```
lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Clear()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Count - 1
    If i > lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Count - 1 Then Exit For
    If Not lbx_OFL_Results.Items(i).Contains(tbx_FindText.Text) Then
        lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Remove(lbx_OFL_Results.Items(i))
        i -= 1
    End If
Next
```

The list box is called "lbx_OFL_Results"
The textbox is called "tbx_FindText"

I start by clearing the list box of all items (when the form loads, it fills the list box will all lines of the text file, so I need to clear it).

Form Load Event Code:

```
Dim lines1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\WPSECHELPER\.data\Outlook Folder Wizard\outlookfolders.txt")
lbx_OFL_Results.Items.AddRange(lines1)
```

For the rest of the code it *seems* to be doing some form of a 'sort search' then removing any excess results.

If anyone can suggest edits to my code, or new code then that would be sublime.

Thanks.

Comment: You clear the ListBox, then start a loop (`For i = 0 To lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Count - 1`) from `0` to `-1`. The loop exits immediately. Did you want to loop `lines1()` instead? Are you also trying to loop backwards, using that `i -= 1` (eve if could work, `i > lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Count - 1` would never be true)?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I've said, it's code from online, suggested as an answer to someone else problem which was similar to mine

Comment: You're not sure about what? What do you want to happen, after you have cleared the `ListBox.Items`? I assume you want to fill it again with the result of the search. So why don't you loop the array of strings (`lines1()`) which contains the data (when you clear the ListBox, all the data it contained is gone)? So you probably need: `lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Clear() lbx_OFL_Results.BeginUpdate() For i as Integer = 0 To lines1().Length - 1 If lines1(i).Contains(tbx_FindText.Text) Then lbx_OFL_Results.Items.Add(lines1(i)) End If Next lbx_OFL_Results.EndUpdate()`. Remove the rest.

Comment: @Jimi Couldn't you have posted that as an answer?

Comment: The line "For i As Integer = 0 To lines1().Length - 1" specifically the brackets part is throwing the error "Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array"

Comment: Yes, that's a copy/paste mistake: remove the brackets.

Comment: @Jimi You're a hero - works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi for the answer.

Code:

```
listbox.Items.Clear() 
listbox.BeginUpdate() 
For i as Integer = 0 To lines1().Length - 1 
If lines1(i).Contains(searchbox.Text) Then 
    listbox.Items.Add(lines1(i)) 
End If 
Next 
listbox.EndUpdate()
```

I have another question which solves how to make this search non case-sensitive. It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689016/case-sensitive-search-from-text-file-fix).